# Put content to right in all browsers

Tags: html, css

I tried to put a content/image to right in CSS but it ended up only working in Chrome and not the other browsers like Mozilla and IE. What did I forget ?

Here is the CSS that works in Chrome

```
.content
{
position:absolute;
right:100px;
width:300px;
}
```

Comment: Put some relevant code

Comment: What you forgot is putting your code so people can check what is going wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your CSS

```
float:right;
```